# A Heat Equation Problem with Dirichlet boundary condition to be solved by Separation of Variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the heat equation $u_{t} = u_{xx}$, $0\le x \le 1$ with boundary data $u(0,t)=0$ and $u(1,t) = 1$, I am supposed to find a solution by the method of separation of variables to the initial condition $u(x,0)= x$.

**My attempt:**

Assume $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, then we have $X(x)T'(t) = X''(x)T(t)$.
$\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} = - \lambda$.

As there can only exist positive eigenvalues under such circumstances, assume $\lambda$ = $\beta^{2}$, then $X''(x)+\beta^{2}X = 0$.

Assume $X = A\cos\beta x + B\sin\beta x$, then $X(0)=0$ leads that $A = 0$. $X(1) =B\sin\beta=1 $ Then $\beta = (2n + \frac{1}{2})\pi.$ The eigenfunctions are therefore $\sin (2n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi x.$

As $T'+\lambda T = 0$, $T = e^{-\lambda t}$. Therefore $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n \sin((2n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi x)}{e^{-\lambda t}} $.

Let $t = 0$, then $u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n \sin((2n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi x)}$ I got stuck then, I'm wondering if I should use Taylor Series to expand it here or if I just missed something important.

I also noticed that $u = x$ seems work for this problem, but it does not depend on t, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A_n$ is the coefficient of the Fourier sine series for $x$ on $[0,1]$.

Therefore, we can write

$$A_n=2\int_0^1 \sin((2n+1/2)\pi x )\,dx=\frac{8}{(4n+1)^2\pi^2}\tag 1$$

A formal way of proceeding is to first note the orthogonality relationship given by

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \sin\left((2n+1/2)\pi x \right)\sin((2m+1/2)\pi x )\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1 \left(\cos(2(m-n)\pi x)-\cos(2(m+n+1/2)\pi x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\begin{cases}\frac12 &,m=n\\\\0&,m\ne n\end{cases} 
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x\sin((2m+1/2)\pi x )\,dx&=\frac{4}{(4m+1)^2\pi^2}\\\\
&\int_0^1  \color{blue}{\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\sin((2n+1/2)\pi x )}_{=x}}\sin((2m+1/2)\pi x )\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \int_0^1 \sin((2n+1/2)\pi x )\sin((2m+1/2)\pi x )\,dx \tag 3\\\\
&=\frac12A_m
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ we assumed the legitimacy of interchanging the order of operations.  Solving for $A_m$ and setting $m=n$ we recover $(1)$ as expected!